# Problemas al cambiar valores dependiendo la condición - Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy creando un punto de venta donde
tengo una tabla que enlista varios artículos previamente buscados, en la tabla hay un `input` en el que coloco la cantidad que se requiere.
El artículo cuenta con distintos precios y cantidad mínima para que se muestre el precio correcto.
Así llamo la función `recalcularPrecio`

```
...
<input @keyup.enter="recalcularPrecio" v-model="detail.quantity">
 ...
```

Y esta sería la función

```
recalcularPrecio(){
 for(var i = 0; i < this.details.length; i++){
   if(this.details[i].quantity < this.details[i].amountTwo){
    this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceList;
   } else if(this.details[i].quantity >= this.details[i].amountTwo && this.details[i].quantity < this.details[i].amountThree){
      this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceTwo;
   } else {
      this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceThree;
   }
  }
 }
```

Con este código logro hacer que cambie el precio pero al ingresar una cantidad inferior a `amountTwo` no regresa al valor `priceList`, se queda con el valor de `priceTwo`

Que es lo que estaré haciendo mal
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No uso vue, pero esto creo que está mal: `for (var i = 0, i < this.details.lenght; i++) {` pues si te fijas separas con una coma el `var i = 0` del resto, cuando creo que deberia ser un punto y coma `;`  (no se si tendrá que ver con tu problema, pero parece ser un error tipográfico al menos)

Comment: Por cierto, es **length**, no **lenght**.

Comment: Oh es cierto, disculpen escribi sin copiar el código y no ví ese detalle, pero el error en ese caso sería de sintaxis, cosa que no pasa pues revisando el código lo tengo bien escrito

Comment: ¿Y esta línea también es un error de sintaxis?  `this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceList;` ... no parece que haga nada, ¿no?

Comment: Siento yo que de ahí nace el problema, creo lo estoy aplicando mal, pues lo que se supone que debe de hacer es que al momento de ser inferior a amountTwo vuelva a su valor base que es priceList pero no lo hace, si coloco un número al azar como valor de `this.details[i].priceList` si hace lo que quiero, quiero suponer que su valor al cambiar a `priceTwo` se queda en ese valor como si fuera el valor original.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas guardar el valor inicial de **priceList** mientras el script esté funcionando podrías hacerlo así:

```
    if (this.details[i].originalPrice == undefined) {
      this.details[i].originalPrice = this.details[i].priceList
    }
```

lo cual crea una nueva propiedad, si no existe previamente, denominada **originalPrice**, que almacenará el valor inicial de priceList.

Después tocaría cambiar esto:

```
if(this.details[i].quantity < this.details[i].amountTwo){
    this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceList;
```

por esto:

```
if (this.details[i].quantity < this.details[i].amountTwo || isNaN(this.details[i].quantity)) {
        this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].originalPrice;
```

donde lo que hacemos es agregar una condición más que se corresponde con la cantidad vacia:  `isNaN(this.details[i].quantity)` y después asignamos a **priceList** su precio original.

Así es como quedaria todo junto:

```
recalcularPrecio() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.details.length; i++) {
    if (this.details[i].originalPrice == undefined) {
      this.details[i].originalPrice = this.details[i].priceList
    }
    if (this.details[i].quantity < this.details[i].amountTwo || isNaN(this.details[i].quantity)) {
        this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].originalPrice;
    } else if (this.details[i].quantity >= this.details[i].amountTwo && this.details[i].quantity < this.details[i].amountThree) {
      this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceTwo;
    } else {
      this.details[i].priceList = this.details[i].priceThree;
    }
  }
}
```

Ya nos dirás si así te funciona.

Comment: Gracias, si bien no soluciono el problema en un 100% logre avanzar y con su aporte logre dar con una manera distinta de ver mi funcion y su logica, gracias

Comment: Vaya, bueno, me alegro que te haya servido (como decia no se Vue pero trasladé todo eso a javascript y me funcionó bien en javsacript).  Por favor, agrega tu una respuesta explicando como lo has solucionado para que la comunidad lo sepa (y yo tambien).